# Route parameter Mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a controller route to get details for an object with given id.

I know how to create a route like /data?id=15, but I would prefer the route to be /data/15.
[image]

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("data/{id}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute(Name="id")] int id)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Can you tell me what that type of route is called?